# Regex for finding 'some' and replacing with 'xyz.some'

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to write a regular expression in ruby for finding a string like 'some' and then replace it with say 'xyz.some'. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't look like you need a regex - plain old `gsub` will do:

```
s = "foo some"
=> "foo some"
s.gsub("some", "xyz.some")
=> "foo xyz.some"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"some string sth".gsub(/some|sth/, 'xyz.\0')
=> "xyz.some string xyz.sth"
```

You find 'some' (or anything other) and then you can use `\0` in replace string (watch for quoting, you need to use `\\0` in `"..."` string) to place all your regex matched. Or you can group matches in your regex and use `\1` - `\9` in your replace string. To place non matching group, just use `(?: )`.

Answer (score 2):

If 'some' can be any arbitrary string (unknown at the time of writing the script),
Use \1 to use the matched group (by position) in your replacement string.

```
a = "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"
str_to_find = "the"

a.gsub(/(#{str_to_find})/, 'xyz.\1')
# => "xyz.the quick brown fox jumped over xyz.the lazy dog"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str = 'lets make some sandwiches'
xyzstr = str.gsub(/some/, "xyz.some");
```